# how can i get .on click to work when .on contextmenu does but .on click does not fully work for dynamic content

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a small snippet of code that is opening another window that is populated with dynamic content

```
$('#table-body').on('click', 'td#showTitle', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('inside');
        $('.quickview').addClass('is-active');
});
```

the above code will execute the log but not add the class however if I change the click to `'contextmenu'` it works with a right click just as expected but this is not the functionality I want I would like to use a normal left click, is there something wrong with the code?

Comment: I think you may have a typo, 'td#showTitle' I believe should be 'td #showTitle'. (with a space to denote it's two different search criteria). Also, are you sure that the DOM element that has the quickview class is loaded when you are clicking the table-body?

Comment: Probably other click event bound somewhere else on any `#showTitle` ancestor remove/toggle the class. You'd have in this handler to filter regarding `event.target`

Comment: @A.Wolff o man silly mistake you are absolutely correct and fixing this has solved my problem, greatly appreciated!!     apparently its time for a coding break ;)